# GRUB2 doesn't display menu but command prompt instead

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I had previously ubuntu and windows 10 installed on my computer. GRUB2 was my boot loader, and on startup I had the grub menu from which I could choose to boot on ubuntu or Windows.

Recently I decided to replace Ubuntu by KDE Neon. I installed it on my previous Ubuntu partitions after formatting them. Installation went successful but now when I restart my computer, GRUB doesn't display the menu as before but only shows the command prompt. If I want the menu to appear I have to execute the following command:

```
grub> set root=(hd1,gpt6)
grub> set prefix=(hd1,gpt6)/boot/grub
grub> insmod normal
grub> normal
```

After this, the menu is displayed and I can see all the kernels installed.

I tried to run the Boot Repair tool, but without success.
[Here is the output of Boot Repair](https://pastebin.com/Vs8xrefa)

I have no clue of what is wrong. Thank you for helping

Comment: Does your /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg file have the UUID of your current root? d2ffa9a0-a69e-478f-b3c8-7287931d0270  If not, edit the file or reinstall grub.  Your old neon EFI entry is still first in boot order, it uses shim, but your new ubuntu entry uses grub -- did you turn off secure boot so that will work?

Comment: You have an old grub for BIOS boot in gpt's protective MBR. That should not be used, but would give the type of error you have if you attempt to boot in BIOS mode. You need to always boot in UEFI mode.